# Django - Remote User Authentication Changes Session IDs

Tags: python, django

I have enabled authentication via `Remote_User` (docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/auth-remote-user/)) and have subclassed `RemoteUserBackend` into a class I've called `MyRemoteUserBackend` to allow for setting of `User` attributes when a user first visits my site (for example, setting their `User` object `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, etc.)

The problem is that, with `MyRemoteUserBackend` enabled, `sessions` don't seem to persist for the users, and data is not passed between `views`, causing broken views.

I have thoroughly tested each View's `forms` and can confirm the problem does not resided with invalid forms.

When I disable/comment out `MyRemoteUserBackend` and instead enable/comment in `RemoteUserBackend` within `SETTINGS`, `sessions` DO persist for the users (`session_key` persists for each user).  When `MyRemoteUserBackend` is enabled, `session_key` does not persists, as if the site thinks what is in fact one user is actually two separate users.

What is wrong with `MyRemoteUserBackend` that is screwing up `sessions` and `sessions_keys` for users?  Let me know if you need any other info.  Thank you.

`SETTINGS`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',  #<--- required
)


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'hrops.MyBackends.MyRemoteUserBackend', #<--- sessions don't persist
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    # 'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
]
```

`MyRemoteUserBackend`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend

class MyRemoteUserBackend(RemoteUserBackend):

    def clean_username(self, username):
        return username.split('\\')[1]  # e.g. "<domain>\\<username>" becomes "<username>"

    def configure_user(self, user):

        from headcount.headcount_new import active_employee_phonelist_details
        # from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

        employee_details = active_employee_phonelist_details(user.username)

        user.first_name = employee_details['first'].strip()
        user.last_name = employee_details['last'].strip()
        user.email = employee_details['email'].strip()

        user.is_active = True
        user.is_staff = False
        user.is_superuser = False
        user.groups.add(7)  # id=7 refers to 'AwaitingSecurity' group  (same id for Prod and Dev)
        user.save()

        return user
```

Comment: Reading [this note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/auth-remote-user/#using-remote-user-on-login-pages-only) at the end of those docs, I suspect you need to usr PersistentRemoteUserMiideleware.

Comment: Ahh, good call.  I did try this and it didn't work BUT I discovered the underlying problem: the remote authentication system (Active Directory) went from capital letter usernames (e.g. "NickB") to lower case (e.g. "nickb") and django was having trouble realizing they are the same user.  I'll have to ask the IT guys why they changed AD.  Thank you.